# Expressions Plus plugin and aggregate functions QGIS 2:18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I used the function `IsSelected('nome_layer')` in `group_by of the aggregate function Sum`:

`sum ($ area, group_by: = IsSelected ('layer'))`

I notice a strange behavior of the labels, sometimes labeled the selected features (fig. 1) sometimes complementary feature (fig.2);

what am I doing wrong?

fig.1
[image: fig. 1]

fig.2
[image: fig. 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why you get different results.

However your expression is constructed in order to obtain for each feature a label corresponding to the sum of the areas of the selected features, which is probably not what you would like to do.

You should probably define a rule-based expression with a case statement on selection and then have the sum calculated, such as this:
[image]

Cheers,

Comment: I realized that NOT work function $area, first put the area attribute.